# Probability with mixed replacement

Tags: probability

If I have a set of 5 objects with equal chance of picking them. If I pick one object it has replacement, but if any of the other 4 are picked it is without replacement. The goal is to pick from the set repeatedly until all 4 non-replaced objects are picked. Is there a formula that can be used to calculate the chance of succeeding after x picks?

Comment: So one object will be replaced and the other four objects will not be replaced?

Comment: Yes, I edited it to make it a little more clear

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote **replaceable** object by **A** and **non-replaceable** object by **B**.
There are 1 A and 4 B.

P(getting **A**)=${\frac{1}{5}}$
P(getting **B**)=$\frac{4}{5}$

For success in **x** attempts, start x from 4, until $x$
x=4: $$(\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{5}$$
x=5: $$(\frac{1}{5})\cdot(\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{5^2}$$

.
.
.
x=n: $$(\frac{1}{5})^{n-4}\cdot(\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{5^{x-3}}$$

Total solution: $$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^3}+....\frac{1}{5^{n-3}}$$
Use GP summation:

> you get $$\frac{1}{4}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{5^{n-3}})$$

Comment: No, after you get on B the chance of getting a B decreases to $\frac 34$ and so on.

Comment: oh yes, B are replaceable...

Comment: Even though there are initially 1 A and 4 B if one B gets picked since it is not replaced there are now 1 A and 3 B so further picks of B have a different chance of occurring. The chance for x=4 should be 4/5*3/4*2/3*1/2=1/5, but I'm not sure of chances of any other x.

Comment: yes, it will be 1/5...edited

Comment: Your chances of picking A when x=5 is a flat 1/5, but it could also be picked after 1 or even 2 B objects are picked which also changes the chances for A being picked. I think the chance of x=5 is something like 1/5*4/5*3/4*2/3*1/2 + 4/5*1/4*3/4*2/3*1/2 + 4/5*3/4*1/3*2/3*1/2 + 4/5*3/4*2/3*1/2*1/2

Comment: ohk,...then its really complicated

Comment: will edit soon..

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from omega: Let us denote **replaceable** object by **A** and **non-replaceable** object by **B**.
There are 1 A and 4 B.

If you get a B on the first pick (probability $\frac 45)$ the chance of a B on the second is $\frac 34$.  If you succeed on those two, you have $\frac 23$ chance to get a B on the third and if that succeeds you have $\frac 12$ chance to get the last one on the fourth, so the chance for $4$ draws is $\frac 15$.

For five draws we can draw the A in any position except the last, so the chance of success is $\frac 15 \cdot \frac 45 \cdot \frac 34\cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 12+ \frac 45 \cdot\frac 14 \cdot \frac 34\cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 12+\frac 45\cdot \frac 34 \cdot\frac 13 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 12+\frac 45\cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 12 \cdot\frac 12=\frac 15(\frac 15+\frac 14+\frac 13+\frac 12)=\frac{77}{300}$
so over a quarter of the time you will succeed in exactly five tries.  If find this amazing.

Doing it for more tries gets very cumbersome this way.  Maybe someone has a better approach.